# Suggestions for development of command and control kind of Natural Language based system

Tags: c#, .net, nlp

Lately, I have developed a keen interest in the speech recognition and natural language processing domain and have been playing around with a few different approaches to build a system which can perform commands based on natural language instructions.

In my study so far, I have come across various NLP tools, but haven't been able to figure out how to utilize them for my purpose.C# is my primary language, and sadly, there is hardly anything available on the dotnet platform for NLP.

In addition to the learning curve, there are various problems with the regular NLP approach as well. Language ambiguity, named entity recognition, sentence boundary detection etc are a few points that add to the complexity. These issues are much more prominent in free form unconstrained language detection and parsing, but for a limited domain, the complexity should be reduced. However, I couldn't really overcome the challenge as most tools have huge static dictionary data or the training process is too complex.

The other major issue is about the conversational approach. Most of the tools do not handle conversational history and have no way to identify the context of the incoming instruction.

I was hoping that some of you guys who have either worked on a similar technology earlier would be able to help me iron out these challenges and point me towards the right direction.

Can you share your experience with various tools, the approaches you took, the roadblocks you faced and how you resolved them during the process.

**Update:** Let me also include a brief overview of what I envision. The system would essentially be a just a command executor that understands simple english. So, if I say, "send an email to john", it should understand that I want to send an email and now ask me questions to get more information about what should be the subject line and the content. Additionally,  if there are more than one Johns in my address book and may be more than one email address for John, the system should be able to identify that too and ask me for further directions.

For the implementation, I think I need following components:

- **Speech to text** converter
- **NLP engine** to parse the text and identify the action and the objects on which the action is to be performed.
- An **execution engine** to create and co-ordinate different agents to perform the different types of actions.

The challenge lies in making the system extensible to be able to support more such actionable features at a later stage with a little modification.

I think I am fine with Speech to text part and execution part. But the pain point is the NLP engine which can understand the natural language correctly and give me exact action and parameters for it.

I have played around with POS taggers. They do not help much with the compound statements, and it gets a little tricky to establish the relationship between various verbs and nouns detected in the sentence.

Another issue is with maintaining the context of previous actions and include it making sense of the current statement.

P.S.: Convert it to a wiki if you feel appropriate. Please don't flame me for asking a generic problem.

Comment: Your question is good on my opinion. But from the language, to the libraries toolset is not an easy answer. Your inner question is You want to learn and implement? or you want to just get practical results in quick way?. If learning, get down to plainn C and many textbooks, if just getting results, consult the people at Apple and Microsoft if you can play with their toys. Sorry if I can't be more clearer or helpful, this is the way I see things.

Comment: I am in for the practical results, but that doesn't mean that I'm looking for shortcuts. If there are tools available to do something, I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Having said that, I would still like to develop the application on my own, using those tools, or work out my own implementation of the tools if they don't fulfill the need. I am actually not able to set a clear path to achieve the goal. Trying to learn from everyone's experiences before taking the plunge.

Comment: Came across AboditNLP.. it sounds promising.. lets see how it goes.. nlp.abodit.com

Answer (score 0):

You can't uncouple learning, from doing coding from scratch, otherwise is meaningless.

Lisp is probably the best language for natural processing, the classic emacs psychiatrist session is an example of what can be accomplished with little work. Its a scientist's language with functional style of programming, the whole thinking is different than regular c like programming, OOP has no bearing on this. Is the oldest still in use language,  a version of it called Scheme is in the MIT introductory course. A classic on the field of AI research.

The problem is you can't easily interface it with your sound input devices, at least most free versions I know of. So you can do the pure logic and awesome of natural language processing in clever ways. But it can't hear you. You can use some stdin/stdout, text file, and database wrappers for independent sound to text and viceversa, but the flux is broken up at uneven levels, and is not natural any longer, because in a natural way of speaking context is lead by understanding of the environment.

If I'm talking with a visiting friend while my AI enabled PC is on and I say: "Just rm -rf everything", how does my machine know who I'm talking about, I silly solution would be that the machine only accept direct addressing: "Computer Do X Y Z", but what if I say to my friend : "In that computer rm -rf everything". Context can only exist through awareness, and Awareness requires some sort of AI.

This is not something to tackle with if/else/then or class hierarchies. Of course at the end of the day lisp machines are coded in C. But is a minimal base, over which you can construct the rest.

So for a mix of learning and "practical approach", you would need to extend a lisp interpreter to add functions to deal with hardware input/output schemes and convert the data back and forwards. This would be trivial and almost secondary on the grand scheme of thigs, but not without considerable effort.

But the most important issue would be the lisp program. You would have to find ways to for example add a intonation property to distinguish stress or eagerness to prioritize an order or to create new context, there is also the problem that people often say non sensical illogical stuff when tired or stressed or by using some local idiom like "chill out", "get a hold of your horses",etc.

A beginner program should not deal with this above example right away, but should be designed to be extensible so it can be able to address such conditions in the future.

Is Easy "do this and that" voice recognition and processing of the order, to contextualized you need a lot of work, both with human issues (language, psychology, culture,etc) and programming Computer Science issues.

An ideal software would be able to use common code to speak both japanese and english, even if grammar and phonetics are completely opposed to each other.

Well this can be almost an exposition of philosophy as well, and can be endless so I'll stop here. I hope this mini essay can be helpful somehow.

Comment: Thanks for investing time and sharing your thoughts. Your perspective makes sense, and I think we CAN separate the voice part out for the time being. But, even with the text based approach, the supported set of activities/tasks that the system would be able to perform, would be very limited in my application. So, the complexity in defining and understanding the context should be less. The challenge lies in making the computer understand all the possible ways that mean the same thing. So, the activity can be to "send an email", but there can be different ways to say it.